# Python, Bokeh, Javascript: use Mongodb database query in callback

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, bokeh

I am using bokeh, and starting to explore the javascript and callbacks aspect of it.

I have a piece of code that contains a datepicker:
I want the callback to perform a query on a mongodb database when it is triggered. 
The thing is that I don't know javascript, and would need some pointers to help me in the right direction.

This is the code I got so far:

```
import pymongo
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, DatePicker
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.formatters import DatetimeTickFormatter
import datetime

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime",plot_width=900, height=200, title="GBP")

mongo=pymongo.MongoClient()
start=datetime.datetime.today().replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0)
end=start+datetime.timedelta(hours=24)
data=pd.DataFrame.from_records(
                mongo.prices["Russia Ruble"].find({"datetime":
                                        {"$gte":start,"$lte":end}}))[["close","datetime"]]

source = ColumnDataSource(data.to_dict(orient="list"))

callback=CustomJS(args=dict(source=source),code='''
var data=source.data;
var f=cb_obj.value

start = f.replace(hour=0,minute=0,second=0,microsecond=0) # use a javacript equivalent of the python code here...
end= start +datetime.timedelta(hours=24) # use a javacript equivalent of the python code here...

data=pd.DataFrame.from_records(
            mongo.prices["Russia Ruble"].find({"datetime":
            {"$gte":start,"$lte":end}}))[["close","datetime"]] # use a javacript equivalent of the python code here...

source.change.emit()

''')

p.line(x = "datetime", y ="close", color="black", source=source)

datepicker=DatePicker(max_date=start,value=start)
datepicker.js_on_change("value",callback)
curdoc().add_root(column(p,datepicker))
```

At first I tried to see whether it was possible to execute some python code along with some javascript (or just some python code..) in the callback, but [this part of the doc](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/callbacks.html#customjs-with-a-python-function) seems to clearly states that this is not possible.

So I accepted the fact that I will need to learn some javascript to progress on my task, and looked into mongo db and javascript. A simple google research on the topic seems to suggest that this [would be close to what node.js is doing](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=T_ciWprrMISxUdLxpjA&q=mongodb%20javascript&oq=mongodb%20javascript&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i203k1l10.790888.795157.0.795540.14.10.4.0.0.0.370.1482.0j4j2j1.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..3.11.1727....0.Y3vQav6mvaE), but I am not so sure about that? Does the bokeh js callbacks equate to server-side javascript? Then [this page](https://zestedesavoir.com/tutoriels/312/debuter-avec-mongodb-pour-node-js/) (sorry it's in french.. but could't find any equivalent in english) explains that in order to use mongodb with node.js, i need to install the mongodb driver using the nodejs package manager (npm)... There I am obviously off track already...

So to recap:
- What would be a good way of performing the simple operations I need to perform in my javascript callback (i.e. creating start time and end time from the date picked by the datepicker, then querying the data from my mongoddb database using that timerange)

Answer (score 1):

Can you post some more information about your web app and what kind of server it's on?

Unfortunately, you won't be able to accomplish what you want with just a callback (even if you learn javascript).

To explain this you have to understand a little bit about how bokeh works under the hood. If you are embedding the bokeh plot using standalone html or by using  `script, div = components(plot)`, then the python is simply creating a customized set of javascript functions and serialization of all the datasources for your plot in one big script that is embedded on your page. The bokeh objects like "Figure", "vbar", "circle" are called models and all of the models are represented in javascript and given their data when they are generated.

That script alone doesn't communicate with your server or database after its been generated. Rather, the callbacks simply modify the properties that the models already have. For instance, a columnDataSource model has certain columns and all those columns are put into javascript so you can have a callback that changes which column is used in a plot for instance.

As the documentation says:

> The architecture of Bokeh is such that high-level “model objects”
>   (representing things like plots, ranges, axes, glyphs, etc.) are
>   created in Python, and then converted to a JSON format that is
>   consumed by the client library, BokehJS

If you want to use python, and your database, to keep your model up to date, that is the use case for bokeh server. Bokeh server is an embeddable server that will keep all the python representations of the models in sync with the javascript ones.

Again per [documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html):

> However, if it were possible to keep the “model objects” in python and
>   in the browser in sync with one another, then more additional and
>   powerful possibilities immediately open up:
>
> > respond to UI and tool events generated in a browser with computations or queries using the full power of python
> >     This capability to synchronize between python and the browser is the main purpose of the Bokeh Server.

Take a look at the [Bokeh Server](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) documentation and see if that might work your use case.

In theory, you could have a JS function fetch JSON data from a different route and push that data into your bokeh models but I don't think that would ever work. Bokeh generates a large number of unique identifiers for every model and model data point which you would need to look up and process on the way in.

There is also a great pycon presentation on the bokeh server. Its a little older from 2015 but is really helpful to understand these concepts. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O5OvOLK-xqQ

Comment: thx for your reply! Yes It was my first stab at the bokeh widget so i was a bit lost. In fact it is very easy to do what I wanted to, be simply using `.on_change` instead of `.js_on_change` as I tried at first. I found the solution by looking up the source code of the reference gallery.